# Django not reading any url pattern other than admin url

Tags: python, django

I am facing one problem while following along with django(1.9) tutorial from newboston which might seem duplicate but I have tried all scenarios to eliminate this bug but failed.
so here it is, 
I have an app named `music` in `djangoLearn` project, but while running this application django is giving this error. It is not reading the any other url pattern other than admin url pattern.

```
Using the URLconf defined in djangoLearn.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
The current URL, music/, didn't match any of these.
```

### djangoLearn\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

### music\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index')
    ]
```

### music\views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h2>Music section</h2>')
```

I have also included my app's name in installed apps section of `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'music',
]
```

I am using python 2.7

Comment: Try putting app_name = 'music' in your music\urls.py before the urlpatterns

Comment: @leelum1 I did that and restarted the server as well but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also tried your code and it works fine for me, I hope you have taken care of these possible mistakes.

1. `music` app is inside your project `djangoLearn`
2. Entered correct URL in web browser
3. Check that is your `server's` port number is correct or not
4. Check if there is error in starting of server
5. Check in `setting.py` file for `ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoLearn.urls'`
6. Also make sure that you are running `server` in the same directory in which you are editing ;-)

If all of these possible mistakes are handled then try for these

**djangoLearn\urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from music.views import index as music_index
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', music_index),
]
```

Comment: And yes settings.py has ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoLearn.urls'

Comment: you can try the code for djangoLearn/urls.py as given above it will be okay if it works but not for good practice

Comment: Nope I tried that code, didn't work :( I am not sure why django only recognizes ^admin pattern not others.also if i try removing everything from urlpatterns, it still recognizes ^admin pattern. why is that ?

Comment: what is the url that you entered in browser?

Comment: check that you are running that server which you are editing in same directory

Comment: Silly me, I had two similar project, in which i made changes and tried running in different project . Thanks it worked !